# Is there anyway to define CIDR block as client_addr value in Consul server config?

Tags: consul

I was getting myself familiar with Consul services and trying things out. However, until now I couldn't find a way to allow specific subnets to send requests to Consul server.

here is my basic consul config.json:

```
{
"server": true,
"datacenter":"dc1",
"data_dir":"/opt/consul",
"bind_addr":"{{ ansible_ssh_host }}",
"client_addr": "0.0.0.0",
"bootstrap_expect": 1,
"node_name": "consul_server",

"ui": true,
"encrypt":"",
"acl" : {
  "enabled" : true,
  "default_policy" : "deny",
  "down_policy" : "extend-cache"
}


}
```

in this case, client_addr is set to anywhere `0.0.0.0`. How can I set it to something like `10.10.4.0/24 10.10.2.0/24` or `10.10.0.0/16`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`client_addr`](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options.html#_client) config option controls which interfaces Consul will bind to for the DNS, HTTP[S], and gRPC listners. You can specify a space-separated list of addresses on the machine on which Consul should listen. E.g.,

```
{
  "client_addr": "192.0.2.10 198.51.100.20 203.0.113.30"
}
```

This won't prevent Consul from being reachable from clients on other CIDRs that can route to one of the listening IPs. You'll need to use a firewall if you want to restrict which IPs can communicate with Consul.

You can, however, restrict which CIDRs Consul will accept API write requests from using the [http_config.allow_write_http_from](https://www.consul.io/docs/agent/options.html#allow_write_http_from) configuration option.

```
{
  "http_config": {
    "allow_write_http_from": [
      "192.0.2.0/24",
      "198.51.100.0/24",
      "203.0.113.0/24"
    ]
  }
}
```

This example config will only allow HTTP PUT/POST/DELETE options from clients residing in one of the listed address ranges.